# Printing a line generates TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm working with Python version 2.7.13. I'm trying to print a line which has the age along with the length of the name.

```
print ('Hello, how are you ?')
print ('im good thanks, what is  your name ?')
myname = raw_input("enter name: ")
print ('Nice name' + myname)
print ('how old  are you?')
my_age = raw_input("enter age : ")
print ('you will be ' + str(int(my_age) + 1) +' in a year' + (len(myname)))
```

When I try to print, I'm getting error like

```
Aruns-MacBook-Pro:~ arun$ python program.py
Hello, how are you ?
im good thanks, what is  your name ?
enter name: arun
Nice namearun
how old  are you?
enter age : 22
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "program.py", line 7, in <module>
    print ('you will be ' + str(int(my_age) + 1) +' in a year' + (len(myname)))
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects.
```

Please explain why.

Comment: You neglected to convert `len(myname)` to a string -- though trying to tack on the *length* of the name seems a bit silly. Do you really want to do that? Why take the length at all? You should, however, insert a space and perhaps a comma.

Answer (score 3):

You correctly convert `int(my_age) + 1` back to a string, but [`len(myname)`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#len) also returns an `int`. If you intend to add `len(myname)` to the end of your string ("concatenate" it with the preceding string, to use the language of the error message, which refers to using `+` to combine two strings), you will need to convert that to a string as well (with `str()` again): `str(len(myname))`.

Comment: Thank you John Coleman and  elethan, got it I missed conversion part.

Comment: @Arun no problem, it happens. Also, just FYI since you are new to the site: when you are referencing other users or replying to them, make sure to put an `@` before their username so that they will get a notification and will see your message.

Answer (score 0):

Use `str(len(myname))`
`len()` returns integer so typecast it to string

Comment: While this might be a valuable hint to solve the problem, a good answer also demonstrates the solution. Please [EDIT](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/5419867/edit) to provide example code to show what you mean. Alternatively, consider writing this as a comment instead

Answer (score 0):

Last line should be :

```
print ('you will be ' + str(int(my_age) + 1) +' in a year' + str((len(myname))))
```